# webElement.click() does not work but action.click(webElement).build().perform(); works

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am quite new at Selenium testing so my apologies in advance if my question sounds elementary.

I am writing a test using Java and Selenium. Sometimes I need to click on a WebElement (for example a button). If I use `element.click();` it does not work but `action.click(element).built().perform();` works, what is the reason?

By the way, this button is off the page and needs to be scrolled down to see it.
Below please find the piece of DOM: `<input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Submit">`

Comment: is it a standart html button? if possible, can you share html code that you have problem?

Comment: Repair your example methods chain to action.click(element).build().perform(); to not confuse others

Answer (score -1):

Here's the answer [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23295483/selenium-webdriver-click-vs-action-click-whats-the-difference)

from your statement

> This button is off the page and needs to be scrolled down to see it.
>   It is clear that WebElement#click() will not work on it.

Comment: but for some other element that are not visible too it works

Comment: They must have been first scrolled into view when loaded. you check this by querying them using isDisplayed() method